# What's the largest variable value in iphone?

Tags: iphone, object, variables

I need to assign 2,554,416,000 to a variable.  What would be the primitive to use, and what would be the object representation class to use?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chuck is right, but in answer to the "object representation", you want `NSNumber` used with the `unsignedInt` methods.

```
NSNumber *myNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:2554416000];
NSUInteger myInt = [myNum unsignedIntValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

2,554,416,000 = 0x9841,4B80 ≤ 0xFFFF,FFFF (`UINT_MAX`), so `uint32_t` (`unsigned int`) or `int64_t` (`long long`).

A signed `int32_t` (`int`) cannot represent this because 0x9841,4B80 > 0x7FFF,FFFF (`INT_MAX`). Storing it in an `int` will make it negative.

Answer (score 1):

This can be represented by a 32-bit unsigned integer (UINT_MAX is about 4 billion). That's actually what NSUInteger is on the iPhone, but if you want to be very specific about the bit width, you could specify a `uint32_t`.

Comment: @Squeegy, your code is using a signed integer, not an unsigned integer. Try an unsigned integer.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out and deleted the comment, hoping you wouldn't see it and I wouldn't look like an idiot.

Comment: @Squeegy, mission accomplished!  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a regular int scaled down by 1000 if you wanted, if this represented a score that could never have the bottom 3 digits hold any info or something similiar.   This would be a way to save a few bits and possibly an entire extra int of space, if that matters.